# Pandas Int64Index with dtype=float

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, pandas

I am relatively new to pandas. I have stumbled onto problems with slicing a pandas DataFrame when an index that originally contained integers has been manipulated such that it contains floats. Consider the following example (somewhat contrived to make it stand on its own; in practice, data are loaded from file):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'i': np.linspace(0, 5, 6).astype(np.int64), 
                   'j': np.linspace(2, 3, 6)})
df.set_index('i', inplace=True)
print(df.index)   # Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype='int64')
df.index = df.index / 10.
print(df.index)   # Int64Index([0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5], dtype='float64')
df[:0.3]
```

The final line raises this exception:

```
TypeError: the slice stop value [None] is not a proper indexer 
for this index type (Int64Index)
```

While it was relatively easy to work around this using an explicit cast along the lines of

```
df.index = np.asarray(df.index, dtype=np.float64) / 10.
```

it took me quite a while to figure out what was going on. What I expected to happen in the original code was that the index would become a `Float64Index` or something similar. When I first noticed the `Int64Index` with `dtype=float` I thought that was wierd. Is there some best practice or similar that I should have followed to avoid this problem?

My pandas version is 0.15.2 on python 3.4.

Comment: On pandas `0.16.0` `df.loc[0:0.3]` and `df.ix[0:0.3]` works fine

Comment: On 0.15.2 `df.loc` works, while `df.ix` fails. Maybe I should try to upgrade... @EdChum does `df[:0.3]` fail on 0.16 too?

Comment: Yes it fails with the same error, it's unclear if this is an error or not, but I can see that there is a mismatch between the type of the index and the type of the index elements, it may be worth raising an [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues)

Comment: @EdChum Thanks for the advice and the help testing on 0.16. I have filed an issue: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9966